# How do I run a function from an input before the code for the function has been read?

Tags: python

I am writing a game, similar to mastermind, and I want a choice bewteen an easy or hard version. I'm not sure how to do this as I need the question before the actual game starts but then there's an error because the function is being called to run before it has been assigned.

```
def difficulty():
    difficulty = input("would you like to the easy or hard version?")
    if difficulty == ("easy"):
        easy()
    elif difficulty == ("hard"):
        hard()
difficulty()
```

This is the start then after is the function with the harder game code then the easier game code. I am trying to run the easy if they request easy and vice versa but the easy () and hard() don't run the code as it isn't assigned yet. I think this is because python reads the code from top to bottom and stops when it finds an error but not sure.

I have never used this before so I apologise if things are unclear or I have done some things wrong.

I am also relatively new to python.

If anybody could help me I would greatly apprectiate it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code shown here. Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think we need a bit more of your code in order to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: You can define `easy` and `hard` after you define `difficulty`, as long as you define them *before* you *call* `difficulty`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback however, somebody has given me a fix to my problem. I do apprectiate your replies though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is quite smart when it comes to identifying functions inside a module. For instance you could do this:

```
def x():
    y()


def y():
    print("Y")

x()
```

and it would execute correctly.

You are right about the execution of a code block that happens from top to bottom, as well as the definitions of those functions will also be constructed top to button, but executed afterwards.

I see some issues in your code.

- you do `difficulty = input("would you like to the easy or hard version?")` but at the same time you have a function called `def difficulty`. There is a conflict there, try to rename that variable.
- you don't need to do `("easy")`, it's overkill, you can compare directly to `"easy"`.

Comment: Thank you, it is now working. I appreciate your help greatly.